# Conditionally replace NA by group

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

I have a dataframe:

```
dataset2_long <- read.table(text="
IDM    time_point           smoking_status
1      smoking6m           0
1      smoking5y           NA   
1      smoking9y           0    
1     smoking13y           0    
2     smoking6m            0     
2     smoking5y            2     
2     smoking9y            0     
2     smoking13y           NA 
3     smoking6m            1
3     smoking5y            2     
3     smoking9y            0     
3     smoking13y           NA", header=TRUE)
```

I want to replace the `NA`s with `0`s within any IDM group which has only `0`s and `NA`s. When I tried using `ifelse`, the values for IDM 2 and 3 also changed to 0.

The output should look like this:

```
IDM    time_point            smoking_status

1      smoking6m           0
1      smoking5y           0   
1      smoking9y           0    
1     smoking13y           0    
2     smoking6m            0     
2     smoking5y            2     
2     smoking9y            0     
2     smoking13y           NA 
3     smoking6m            1
3     smoking5y            2     
3     smoking9y            0     
3     smoking13y           NA
```

This is the code I created:

```
dataset2_long <- dataset2_long %>%
  group_by(IDM) %>%
  mutate(smoking_status = ifelse(all(is.na(smoking_status) | smoking_status == 0), replace(smoking_status, is.na(smoking_status), 0), smoking_status))
```

Answer (score 1):

The part you were missing withing your `ifelse` function call was a check if the *current* row is `NA`:

```
dataset2_long %>%
    group_by(IDM) %>%
    mutate(smoking_status  = ifelse(all(is.na(smoking_status) | smoking_status == 0) & is.na(smoking_status), 0, smoking_status))
```

Also, the bit using `replace()` was unnecessary, because you're overwriting the column anyway. That is more useful for string replacement

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary flag `within` the data.

```
within(dat, {
  flag <- ave(smoking_status, IDM, FUN=\(x) all(is.na(x) | x == 0))
  smoking_status[as.logical(flag)] <- 0
  rm(flag)
})
#    IDM time_point smoking_status
# 1    1  smoking6m              0
# 2    1  smoking5y              0
# 3    1  smoking9y              0
# 4    1 smoking13y              0
# 5    2  smoking6m              0
# 6    2  smoking5y              2
# 7    2  smoking9y              0
# 8    2 smoking13y             NA
# 9    3  smoking6m              1
# 10   3  smoking5y              2
# 11   3  smoking9y              0
# 12   3 smoking13y             NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(IDM = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), time_point = c("smoking6m", "smoking5y", "smoking9y", 
"smoking13y", "smoking6m", "smoking5y", "smoking9y", "smoking13y", 
"smoking6m", "smoking5y", "smoking9y", "smoking13y"), smoking_status = c(0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, NA, 1L, 2L, 0L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(n=max(smoking_status, na.rm = T), .by=IDM,
             smoking_status2=smoking_status) %>% fill(smoking_status2) %>% 
  mutate(smoking_status=ifelse(n==0, smoking_status2,smoking_status)) %>% 
  select(-c(n,smoking_status2))

# output

# A tibble: 12 × 3
     IDM time_point smoking_status
   <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
 1     1 smoking6m               0
 2     1 smoking5y               0
 3     1 smoking9y               0
 4     1 smoking13y              0
 5     2 smoking6m               0
 6     2 smoking5y               2
 7     2 smoking9y               0
 8     2 smoking13y             NA
 9     3 smoking6m               1
10     3 smoking5y               2
11     3 smoking9y               0
12     3 smoking13y             NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `ifelse()` statement, it's just the condition has to take into account all the values within the group.  In the code below, I use the following conditions: `is.na(smoking_status) & all(na.omit(smoking_status) == 0)`.  The first captures whether `smoking_status` is missing and the second whether all non-missing values for that group are zero.  If both conditions hold, replace `smoking_status` with zero.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- read.table(textConnection("IDM time_point smoking_status
1 smoking6m 0 
1 smoking5y NA
1 smoking9y 0
1 smoking13y 0
2 smoking6m 0
2 smoking5y 2
2 smoking9y 0
2 smoking13y NA 
3 smoking6m 1 
3 smoking5y 2
3 smoking9y 0
3 smoking13y NA"), header=TRUE)

dat %>% 
  group_by(IDM) %>% 
  mutate(smoking_status = ifelse(is.na(smoking_status) & 
                                   all(na.omit(smoking_status) == 0), 
                                 0, 
                                 smoking_status))
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#> # Groups:   IDM [3]
#>      IDM time_point smoking_status
#>    <int> <chr>               <dbl>
#>  1     1 smoking6m               0
#>  2     1 smoking5y               0
#>  3     1 smoking9y               0
#>  4     1 smoking13y              0
#>  5     2 smoking6m               0
#>  6     2 smoking5y               2
#>  7     2 smoking9y               0
#>  8     2 smoking13y             NA
#>  9     3 smoking6m               1
#> 10     3 smoking5y               2
#> 11     3 smoking9y               0
#> 12     3 smoking13y             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>